# Error running RealSense D435 on Ubuntu 16.04(4.4.0-131-generic)

Tags: ros, realsense

I am getting an error message when running `realsense-viewer`. The realsense window does appear and I can also run the launch files.

```
WARNING [139658086876928] (sensor.cpp:338) Unregistered Media formats : [ UYVY ]; Supported: [ ]
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 0. Get your Ubuntu up to date by running the following commands in a Terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Step 1. Make sure you have the latest firmware on your D400 RealSense
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27954/Latest-Firmware-for-Intel-RealSense-D400-Product-Family

Step 2. Follow the build tutorial here
https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/blob/master/doc/distribution_linux.md

Step 3. Unplug the camera and plug it back again (a system restart also helps in some cases)

Step 4. Run `realsense-viewer`